# Drag and Drop in QAbstractItemModel PySide PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have been chipping away at learning how to implement QAbstractItemModel with QTreeView, and a custom Item class, and I have everything working except for the drag and drop.

Ultimately I would like to be able to switch between Moving and Copying items with the shift Key, but for now I am just trying to get the InternalMove to work at all....

I am re-implementing mimeData and dropMimeData like this....

```
class BuildModel( QAbstractItemModel ):
    def __init__( self, root):
        super( BuildModel, self ).__init__()

    def mimeTypes( self ):
        return ['sushi-build-items']

    def mimeData( self, indices ):
        mimedata = QMimeData()
        mimedata.setData('sushi-build-items', self.getSerializedData(indices) )
        return mimedata

    def dropMimeData( self, mimedata, action, row, column, parentIndex ):
        if not mimedata.hasFormat( 'sushi-build-items' ):
            return False
        data = pickle.loads((str(mimedata.data('sushi-build-items'))))
        items = dataToItems(data)
        self.insertItems(row, items, parentIndex)
        return True

    def insertItems( self, row, items, parentIndex):
        parent = self.itemFromIndex(parentIndex)
        self.beginInsertRows( parentIndex, row, row+len(items)-1 )
        if row == -1:
            parent.addChildren(items)
        else:
            parent.insertChildren(row, items)
        self.endInsertRows()
        self.dataChanged.emit(parentIndex, parentIndex)
        return True
```

And my tree view is set to InternalMove like this....

```
class TreeView(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, model = None):

        super(TreeView, self).__init__(parent = parent)
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
```

But when I drag and drop the source item stays as it is, and it just drops a duplicate item.
Shouldn't the removal of the dragged item be handled by the TreeView?  If not where do I remove it manually?

I am convinced I am missing something here..

Comment: Try to implement virtual `moveRows` and `removeRows` methods and check if they are called by the view during drags. Also you definitely need to implement `supportedDropActions` to return `Qt.MoveAction | Qt.CopyAction`.

Comment: As said before, `def supportedDropActions(self): return QtCore.Qt.MoveAction | QtCore.Qt.CopyAction` did the tricks for me. Good to know because I didn't see that in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the `removeRows` method in your model; it should get called automatically.

Comment: In my case, if `dropMimeData` returns `False`, the `removeRows` is not called.When we want to delete them by ourselves, it is better. In fact, there are some cases like that.For example, when the selection mode is `ContinguousSelection`,  I select multi items and move them, it is not good. Because `removeRows` is called one by one, and the item list gets decreased with it, but the position in the argument get increased vice versa. I can't say my code is absolutely right, though.